Vue.js acess components values
I have a question:
I have two files. I want to dynamically access the value of assignmentData of the one file when it's value changes. How do I do this? It's changed when I mark a checkbox...
Component code:
<template>

    <form class="form-horizontal">

        <div class="form-group" >
            <label for="kursAusgewählt" class="col-sm-4 control-label"  ></label> 
           <template v-if="data_for_assignment.kurs.priority_system == 0">
                <div class="col-smfz-11" style="margin-top: -40px;" >
                    <label id="kursAusgewählt" class="checkbox-container" >
                        
                        <input  type="checkbox" :checked="assignmentData.selected" @change="update('selected', $event.target.checked)">
                        <span class="checkmark" style="margin-left: -40px; margin-top:33px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Auswählen</span> 
                        
                    </label>
                </div>
            </template>
        
            <template v-if="data_for_assignment.kurs.priority_system == 1" >
                <div class="col-smfz-6" >
                    <select v-model="assignmentData.selected_prio" class="form-control inline" data-width="85px" style="color:gray; ;width: 100px; margin-left:-40px;margin-top: -8px;">
                        <option v-for="prio in data_for_assignment.prios" :key="prio" :value="prio">
                            <template v-if="prio == 0">
                              Priorität &nbsp; wählen &nbsp;
                            </template>
                            <template v-else>
                                Priorität {{prio}}
                            </template>
                        </option>
                    </select>   
                </div>
            </template>
            
        </div>

    </form>

<script>

    import modal from "../../modal.vue"

    export default {
        name: 'anmeldenScheduleComponent',
        components: {
            modal
        },
        props: {
            assignmentData: [],
            data_for_assignment: {},
            
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                value_default: {
                    selected: false,
                    selected_prio: 0,
                },
                showModal: false,
            }
        },
        updated (){
            this.setDefault();
        },
        mounted(){
            this.setDefault();
        },
        methods: {
        
            update(key, value) {
                this.assignmentData[key] = value;
                this.$emit('update:assignmentData', this.assignmentData);
                
            },

            setDefault() {
                if (this.assignmentData == [] || !this.assignmentData.assignedDefault){
                    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.value_default)) {
                        this.assignmentData[key] ??= value;
                    }
                    
                    this.$emit('update:assignmentData', this.assignmentData);
                    this.assignmentData.assignedDefault = true;
                }
            },
            
        },
        computed: {
            
        }
    }
</script>

and here the code of the main file:
<template>


    <div class="home">
        
        <div class="body content rows scroll-y">
            <div class="page-heading animated fadeInDownBig">
                <h1>Kursanmeldung</h1>
            
                
            </div>
            <box_content>
                <h2><strong>Anmeldbare Kurses</strong>
               
                    <div class="" style="margin-top: 4px; margin-left: 150px; position: absolute; top: 16px; color: #909090">
                        <a class="additional-icon" id="dropdownErklaerung" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" style="color: #909090"><i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i></a>
        
                        <div class="fragezeichenErklaerung dropdown-menu pull-right" style="margin-right: -150px" aria-labelledby="dropdownErklaerung">
                            In diesem Menü können Sie die Kurse einsehen, für welche Sie sich anmelden können.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                
                    <template v-if="kurseAnmeldbar && kurseAnmeldbar.length > 0">
                        <div class="pull-right selectobenrechts" style="margin-top: -10px; max-width: 368px;">
                            <select v-model="selected_kurs_id" class="form-control inline" data-width="150px" style="z-index:0 !important; display: inline-block;;" @change="updateSelection">
                                <option v-for="kurs in kurseAnmeldbar" :key="kurs.id" :value="kurs.id">
                                    {{kurs.name}}
                                </option>
                            </select>       
                        </div>
                    </template>
     
                </h2>

                <template v-if="kurseAnmeldbar && kurseAnmeldbar.length > 0">
                    <div align="right" class="form-group">      
                        <div class="btn-toolbar">
                            <template v-if="!anmeldenAllowed">
                                <b>{{ anmeldenDisabledReason }}</b>
                            </template>   
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"   v-on:click="kursAnmelden"  :disabled="!anmeldenAllowed">Anmeldung absenden</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="textInput">Zusätzliche Bemerkung zur Anmeldung</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="textInput" placeholder="Hier zusätzliche Bemerkungen eingeben...">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="padding: 20px;">
                        <scheduler :assignments="termine" :allow_add_assignment="false" :allow_delete_assignment="false" :allow_drag_and_drop="false" :allow_resize="false" :slot_component_name="'anmeldenScheduleComponent'" v-bind:data_for_assignment="dataForAssignment" />
                    </div>

                </template>
                <template v-else>
                    <center> 
                        <h2>Es sind keine anmeldbaren Kurse vorhanden.</h2> 
                    </center>
                </template>
  

            </box_content>
            
        </div>
    </div>
 </template>
 <script>

    import {apiRequest} from "../../services/api.js"
    import box_content from "../../components/box_content.vue"
    import scheduler from "../../components/scheduler/scheduler.vue"
    import anmeldenScheduleComponent from "../../components/scheduler/slotComponents/anmeldenScheduleComponent.vue"

    import {timestringToDate} from "../../services/service_scheduler.js" 

    export default { 
      components: {
        scheduler, box_content, anmeldenScheduleComponent, 
      },
      
      
      data: function() {
          return {
            kurseAnmeldbar: [],
            selected_kurs_id: -1, 
            selected_kurs: {},
            assignmentData:{},
            
           
          }
        
      },
      
      methods: {
        
        
        async update ()  {
            try{
                this.kurseAnmeldbar = await apiRequest("get", "/kursverwaltung/kurse/anmeldbar");
            }catch{
                console.log("ERROR")
            }
            if (this.kurseAnmeldbar != null && this.kurseAnmeldbar.length > 0 && this.selected_kurs_id == -1){
                this.selected_kurs_id = this.kurseAnmeldbar[0].id;
                this.updateSelection();
            }
        },
        updateSelection(){
          for (const kurs of this.kurseAnmeldbar){
            if (kurs.id == this.selected_kurs_id){
                this.selected_kurs = kurs;
            }
          }
        },   
        async kursAnmelden() {
           let bemerkung= document.getElementById("textInput").value
            let belegungen = [];
            for (const termin of this.selected_kurs.termine){

                for (const real_termin of termin.reale_termine){
                    if (this.selected_kurs.priority_system == 0){ //&& real_termin.selected==true){
                        belegungen.push({
                            
                            "termin": 2,            //real_termin, //real_termin,//2,// termin.selected,//real_termin,
                            "mitglied":0,
                            "prio": null,
                            "bemerkung": bemerkung,
                            //"selected": true,
                        })
                     

                    }
                    else{
                        belegungen.push({
                           // "termin": real_termin,
                           "termin": 1,//termin.selected,//real_termin,
                            "mitglied":0,
                            "prio": real_termin.selected_prio,
                            "bemerkung": bemerkung,
                            //"prio": termin.selected_prio,
                        })
                    }
                }
            }
            try{      
                await apiRequest("post", "kursverwaltung/anmelden", 
                    {
                    "kurs":  this.selected_kurs.id,
                    "belegungen": belegungen,
                    }
                );
                this.requestResponse = "Belegung erfolgreich gespeichert"
            }catch(ex){
                this.requestResponse="Fehler"            }

            this.update();

        }
    },
      
    async mounted (){
          
        let dependency = document.createElement('script')
        dependency.setAttribute('src', '../../../../' + "js/script.js")
        document.head.appendChild(dependency)
        this.update();
        
      },
      computed: {
        
        termine(){
            let termine = []
            let counter = 0;
            for (let termin of this.selected_kurs.termine){
                termin.starttime = new Date(termin.starttime);
                termin.endtime = new Date(termin.endtime);
                termin.column_id = termin.wochentag;
                termin.title = "Termin " + (counter+1);
                //termin.selected = false;
                

                if (termin.selected_prio){
                    termin.selected_prio = String(termin.selected_prio)
                }

                termin.reale_termine = [] //Das brauchen wir für den Overlap. Also welche realen Termine der Termin abdeckt
                let overlap = false;
                let overlap_termin = null;
                for (let termin2 of termine){
                    if (termin.starttime.getTime() == termin2.starttime.getTime() && termin.endtime.getTime() == termin2.endtime.getTime() && termin.column_id == termin2.column_id){
                        overlap = true;
                        overlap_termin = termin2;
                    }
                }
                if (!overlap){
                    termin.reale_termine.push(termin.id);
                    termine.push(termin);                
                    counter++;
                } 
                else{
                    termin.hide = true;
                    overlap_termin.reale_termine.push(termin.id);
                }
                
            }
            return termine;
        },
        dataForAssignment(){
            let prios = Array.from(Array(this.selected_kurs.maximum_selections+1).keys())
            return {
                kurs: this.selected_kurs,
                prios: prios,
            }
        },
        anmeldenAllowed() {

            return this.anmeldenDisabledReason === ""; //Kann sein, dass hier der Render Bug entsteht

        },
        anmeldenDisabledReason () {
            const kurs = this.selected_kurs;
            let selectedTermineCount = 0;
            if (kurs.priority_system === 0) {
                selectedTermineCount = kurs.termine.filter(termine => termine.selected).length;
            }
            else if (kurs.priority_system === 1) {
                const selectedPriorities = [];
                for (const termin of kurs.termine) {
                    if (termin.selected_prio !== undefined && termin.selected_prio !== null && termin.selected_prio !== "" && termin.selected_prio !== "0" && termin.selected_prio !== 0) {
                        if (selectedPriorities.includes(termin.selected_prio)) {
                            return "  Die Prioritätsstufe " + termin.selected_prio + " ist doppelt belegt"
                        }
                        selectedPriorities.push(termin.selected_prio);
                    }
                }
                selectedTermineCount = selectedPriorities.length 
            }
            if (selectedTermineCount < kurs.minimial_selections){
                    return "Bitte wählen Sie mindestens " + kurs.minimial_selections + " Termin(e)"
                }
            else if (selectedTermineCount > kurs.maximum_selections){
                return "Bitte wählen Sie maximal " + kurs.maximum_selections + " Termin(e)"
            }
            else{
                return ""
            }    
        }
    }
}

</script>

<style>



</style>

I tried multiple times by v-mode, v-bind and so on but always got an error or that the value I try to access is "undefined"...
Thanks for your help!

What's the state you have in the first component and want to use in the other? One simple way would be to use a store like Pinia, but it might be overkill in this situation.

Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for the problem. There's too much irrelevant code

@kissu what do you mean by state? I have a ceckbox for a bunch of assignments. If the checkbox is marked, the value of this.assignmentData.selected changes to true or false. i need to be able to get this boolean value of this.assignmemntData.selected in the other vue file

If you use Vue, you are supposed to use state. This is how you do set a state for a checkbox. Otherwise, it would be by accessing the elements in the DOM as in vanilla JS. But then you do not have any reactivity. TLDR: use vanilla JS or VueJS with a state for your UI components/toggles/inputs etc.
